# XAML UWP - How to use animations in RenderTransform on elements in a ItemsControl (Data Binding)

Tags: xaml, animation, data-binding, uwp

I want to show a collection of images with entry animations (opacity, translation and rescaling) in a UWP app.

How do I apply unique storyboards to each of these images within the `ItemsControl.ItemTemplate` `DataTemplate` so that each image has unique translations and sizes? While the animations are the same, their parameters do change from image to image.

Have been looking for several days on something that works reliably, and all I have found so far is stuff that will not work in UWP apps.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I apply unique storyboards to each of these images

Firstly, since you want each of these images has a different animation, I suggest to have a property for the image instance to indicate which animation the image will play.

Then secondly, we need to resolve the issue that with different property value to trigger different `Storyboard`. For this we could consider to use [`DataTriggerBehavior`](https://github.com/Microsoft/XamlBehaviors/wiki/DataTriggerBehavior) of [`XamlBehaviors`](https://github.com/Microsoft/XamlBehaviors) package. Install the `XamlBehaviors` Nuget package through [this link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Uwp.Managed/).

At last binding the corresponding `Storyboard`  to the trigger it will work.
The following is a completed working demo you could have a test.

XAML

```
...
xmlns:Interactions="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"
xmlns:Interactivity="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
xmlns:Media="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Media"
...
<ItemsControl x:Name="itemcontrol">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.Resources>
                    <Storyboard x:Name="StoryBoardOpacity">
                        <DoubleAnimation
                            Storyboard.TargetName="img"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                            From="0.0"
                            To="1.0"
                            Duration="0:0:5" />
                    </Storyboard>
                    <Storyboard x:Name="StoryboardScale">
                        <DoubleAnimation
                            Storyboard.TargetName="transform"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleX"
                            From="1.0"
                            To="2.0"
                            Duration="0:0:5" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </Grid.Resources>
                <Image
                    x:Name="img"
                    Width="100"
                    Height="100"
                    Source="{Binding imageurl}">
                    <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        <Interactions:DataTriggerBehavior
                            Binding="{Binding storyboard}"
                            ComparisonCondition="Equal"
                            Value="Opacity">
                            <Media:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource StoryBoardOpacity}" />
                        </Interactions:DataTriggerBehavior>
                        <Interactions:DataTriggerBehavior
                            Binding="{Binding storyboard}"
                            ComparisonCondition="Equal"
                            Value="Scale">
                            <Media:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource StoryboardScale}" />
                        </Interactions:DataTriggerBehavior>
                    </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <Image.RenderTransform>
                        <CompositeTransform x:Name="transform" />
                    </Image.RenderTransform>
                </Image>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Code behind

```cs
    private ObservableCollection<OneImage> imageSources;
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        imageSources = new ObservableCollection<OneImage>()
        {
            new OneImage()
            {
                imageurl="ms-appx:///Assets/caffe1.jpg",
                storyboard="Opacity"
            },
            new OneImage()
            {
                imageurl="ms-appx:///Assets/caffe2.jpg",
                storyboard="Opacity"
            },
            new OneImage()
            {
                imageurl="ms-appx:///Assets/caffe3.jpg",
                storyboard="Scale"
            }
        };
        itemcontrol.ItemsSource = imageSources;
    }

    public class OneImage
    {
        public string imageurl { get; set; }
        public string storyboard { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, Sunteen! Now comes the hard part: I want to position the images across the available space of the `ItemsControl`, which means that I have to calculate the starting and end coordinates based on the size of the available space. When the user changes the layout, I will have to change those values. How can I do that? Would I have to reset the animations and restart with new values? How?

Comment: Plus, the NuGet package you suggest has not seen an update in more than  a year. I am loath to put something like that into production code...

Comment: @J.H. For the first comment, since you didn't provide any code snippet, I'm not sure what's your layout for the `ItemsControl`. And I'm a little confused about the questions follow. Since this is completed the new issue about layout, please ask a new thread with details and some code snippet. For the second one, since the package is open source, you could reference it to write your own code to implement the feature.

Comment: not sure what is missing in my question... I specifically mentioned that I needed to use translations and rescaling for each single element. I am using a `Canvas` as the container. The elements are to appear in the center of the canvas and then float to their respective end positions.  I got it to work (somewhat), by creating new animations on DataContext events for each element and causing the DataContext to change every time the canvas resizes (triggering the DataContext events). It tends to blow up rather impressively, as it seems difficult to stop ongoing animations.

Comment: Just to clarify.  Am I correct that you could have made `StoryboardScale` target name `img` and the property `(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.ScaleX)` instead of naming `CompositeTransform` `transform` and accessing `ScaleX` directly?