# Can't resolve TargetName when triggering using XamlBehaviors

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I was attempting to get an image to rotate indefinitely as a waiting throbber when `State` is in a running state, and to reset it's angle and stop rotating when in any other state.  I took [XAML UWP - How to use animations in RenderTransform on elements in a ItemsControl (Data Binding)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48300444/xaml-uwp-how-to-use-animations-in-rendertransform-on-elements-in-a-itemscontro) as my inspiration.

Here's my code:

```xml
<Page
    x:Class="GUI.Views.Content.Ingest"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:GUI.Views.Content"
    xmlns:dcd="using:GUI.Views.DCD"
    xmlns:helper="using:GUI.Helpers"
    xmlns:conv="using:GUI.Converters"
    xmlns:lc ="using:GuiSharedLibrary.LoggingControls"
    xmlns:localConv="using:GUI.Converters.Localization_Converters"
    xmlns:tms="using:TMSClient.TMSService"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:permissionConv="using:GUI.Converters.Permission_Converters"
    
    xmlns:Interactions="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"
    xmlns:Interactivity="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
    xmlns:Media="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Media"
    
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    DataContext = "{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=IngestViewModel }">
    <Page.Resources>
        <!-- Storyboard to rotate icon indefinitely -->
        <Storyboard x:Name="StoryboardRotate">
            <DoubleAnimation
                Storyboard.TargetName="stateIcon"
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)"
                From="0" To="360" Duration="0:0:5" RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
        </Storyboard>

        <!-- Storyboard to reset and stop rotating icon -->
        <Storyboard x:Name="StoryboardStopRotate">
            <DoubleAnimation
                Storyboard.TargetName="stateIcon"
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)"
                From="0" To="0" RepeatBehavior="1x"/>
        </Storyboard>
        
        <conv:IsRunningStateConverter x:Key="IsRunningStateConverter"/>
...
            <Image x:Name="stateIcon" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="4" Source="{Binding State, Converter={StaticResource IngestJobStateToIconConverter}}" RenderTransformOrigin=".5, .5">
                <Image.RenderTransform>
                    <RotateTransform />
                </Image.RenderTransform>
                <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <Interactions:DataTriggerBehavior
                            Binding="{Binding State, Converter={StaticResource IsRunningStateConverter}}"
                            ComparisonCondition="Equal"
                            Value="true">
                        <Media:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource StoryboardRotate}" />
                    </Interactions:DataTriggerBehavior>
                    <Interactions:DataTriggerBehavior
                            Binding="{Binding State, Converter={StaticResource IsRunningStateConverter}}"
                            ComparisonCondition="Equal"
                            Value="false">
                        <Media:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource StoryboardStopRotate}" />
                    </Interactions:DataTriggerBehavior>
                </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            </Image>
...
```

However, when `State` changes value, the converter is hit (correct) that returns a `bool` and then I get an exception in the code saying:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException was unhandled by user code
  ErrorCode=-2146496512
  HResult=-2146496512
  Message=No installed components were detected.

Cannot resolve TargetName stateIcon.
```

The exception happens where `State` is being assigned a value.

The `Image` tag is named `stateIcon`.  I've even attempted to do what was done in the answer from where I drew my inspiration from and named the `RotateTransform` element and used that in my `TargetName`, but it just changed the error to not being able to resolve that name.

What am I missing?

Comment: Could you please tell me what do you want to implement?

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT, updated the text at the beginning of the question.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was caused by the `Image` tag being in an `ItemControl.ItemTemplate` tag (something I didn't realise I should have added to the question).  This is because (I would assume) that the image with that name is one of many instances.  Because of this, having the `StoryBoard`s in the `Page.Resources` results in having many tags that have the same `x:Name`, thus not being able to determine which `Image` tag to change.  That or the `Image` tag doesn't exist and isn't updated outside of the template when an instance is generated.

Moving the `StoryBoard`s from the `Page.Resources` to the local `Grid.Resources` within the `ItemControl.ItemTemplate` tag, fixed the issue because within that scope, there was only one instance of an `Image` tag with the name `stateIcon`.  That or the resource is generated at the same time as the image, so it can reference it.

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT, can you tell me which of my explanations is correct?  Is the `x:Name` ambiguous or is the DOM info not updated?